# In iOS uiwebview you can see/capture what the user is typing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, secure-coding

I am using UIWebView in my application to open a page where the user enters some sensitive data in the webpage input field which is opened in the web view.

Queries I have are :

1. Is UIWebview secure?
2. From uiwebview you can see/capture what the user is typing.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Perhaps `SFSafariViewController` introduced in iOS9 would suit your needs for added protection. It runs in a different process and the app itself cannot access the typed data by the user. It's useful for web based authentication and such.

Comment: Or even push it further with iOS11 `SFAuthenticationSession` or iOS12 `ASWebAuthenticationSession`

Comment: how can I handle a callback with redirect Url without using URL schema?